# create fiscal week number

Tags: sql, sql-server, fiscal

How can I put the below logic into a format SQL Server will use to create a fiscal week number ?

```
if (datepart(week,getdate())-4) <= 0  then (datepart(week,getdate())+49) else (datepart(week,getdate())-4)
```

Comment: Just make a table with the fiscal weeks. You'll thank me later.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us what you are debugging.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, we do have a built in Calendar but it lost overly complicated for a new user like me, thinking of just quickly creating my own now though !

Comment: That's the part what @JacobH means with thanking him later -- at point when you don't have to fix places you have already forgotten where you just "quickly created" something.

Comment: @JamesZ and then when you need to use the fiscal weeks in 10 different reports you have to copy the "quickly created something" 10 times. Then when you need to modify it you have to find all the reports and quickly update the quickly created thing 10 more times... then when you need a new report you have to go find the quickly created something again and copy it to your new code and... then the next time you go back to those 10 places and update your code except this time you forgot about the 11th place and...you see where I'm going of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CASE Statement should work:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (datepart(week,getdate())-4) <= 0
        THEN datepart(week,getdate())+49
    ELSE
        datepart(week,getdate())-4
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (DATEPART(WEEK, getdate()) - 4) <= 0
            THEN DATEPART(WEEK, getdate()) + 49
            ELSE DATEPART(WEEK, getdate()) - 4
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012+, you can use [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql)

```
SELECT IIF((datepart(week, getdate())-4) <= 0, datepart(week, getdate()) + 49, datepart(week, getdate()) - 4 )
```

For Less than SQL Server 2012 version, you may use [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql).